# Python SSL Socket: receiving and sending from both server and client

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, client

OK, So I'm trying to get back and forth communication between server and client over an SSL socket connection. What I thought would be the best way to do this would have been to implement 2 threads in each, each thread acting as a server and a client respectively.But when I implement this code (obviously using opposite corresponding ports in other server/client):

```
#secserv.py

import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL
import threading
import time

class SecureIn(threading.Thread):
  context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
  context.use_privatekey_file('key')
  context.use_certificate_file('cert')

  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s = SSL.Connection(context, s)
  s.bind(('', 5570))
  def run(self):
    while True:
      self.s.listen(5)
      (connection, address) = self.s.accept()
      print repr(connection.recv(5570))


class SecureOut(threading.Thread):
  time.sleep(6)
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.connect(('localhost', 12345))
  sslSocket = socket.ssl(s)
  print repr(sslSocket.server())
  print repr(sslSocket.issuer())
  def run(self):
    sslSocket.write('Hello secure socket\n')

  s.close()


si = SecureIn()
si.start()
time.sleep(6)
so = SecureOut()
so.start()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "secserv.py", line 25, in <module>
    class SecureOut(threading.Thread):
  File "secserv.py", line 28, in SecureOut
    s.connect(('localhost', 12345))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Alternatively I have tried getting a standalone server to send even a broadcast message to all clients. I've searched high and low, but I can't seem to find a working way to do it with SSL socket, only regular sockets. When I try either `s.write()` or `s.sendall()` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "secserv.py", line 19, in <module>
    s.write('hello client\n')
OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL_write', 'uninitialized')]
```

from this code:

```
import socket
from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('key')
context.use_certificate_file('cert') 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = SSL.Connection(context, s)
s.bind(('', 12345))
while True:
    s.listen(5) 
    (connection, address) = s.accept()
    print repr(connection.recv(12345))
    #This could also be s.sendall()
    s.write('hello client\n')
```

Please help me StackOverFlow, you're my only hope. I know this should be easy, but my brain is so strained at this point, I just can't think anymore.

Also, I'm fairly new to python, so there is a large possibility that there's something about the way it operates/loads classes/etc, that I just don't get.

EDIT: OK, I know this code is bad. It isn't a product that's going to market, it will never be run live, this is just me trying to get a concept working, and that concept is: get server and client sending messages to each other over a python ssl connection.

I know this is terrible code, but I just need to know how to get the server to send a message back, because whenever I try it I get the error at the end.

Comment: Why do you need two sockets? Sockets are bidirectional; you don't need to make a separate connection back from the server to the client to send data. (And you probably don't want to, because many clients on the internet are behind NAT and can't be reached directly in this way.) Is there something to your design that makes this necessary that you haven't explained?

Comment: Well originally there were some clients I wanted to talk with (from the server) exclusively, but I now realise I don't need that.

I then tried to get the server to send data back, but like it says, I can't find the SSL way to do that with sockets, it keeps throwing me an error.

Comment: Meanwhile, the error you're getting is telling you that nobody's listening on port 12345. Are you sure the client is actually trying to listen at this point? Looking at your code, if both sides are doing "do everything one way, then sleep 6 seconds, then do everything the other way", it's perfectly plausible that the server would try to connect before the client had started listening…

Comment: Well I was under the assumption that the `while True:` in it's own thread would continue running while the other thread ran. That and the fact that the other version of this running concurrently would be the other way around, so to speak, setting up the server on port 12345 and waiting for connections, then attempting to send on 5570.

Answer (score 5):

Your design seems to be misguided at many levels.

First, you do not need two sockets to send data in both directions; sockets are bidirectional.

And you probably do not *want* to make a connection from the server back to the client—that might work in localhost testing, but once you deploy to the internet, most of the clients will be behind NAT routers, and won't have public addresses that you can connect to.

Meanwhile, your logic is very odd. You start the connection in one direction, then sleep 6 seconds, then start the connection in the other direction. Why would you want to do that?

If the server calls its `SecureOut` before, or even around the same time, as the client calls its `SecureIn`, it will try to connect before there's anyone listening, which will get exactly the error you're seeing.

Also, you've got a very weird run loop for each thread:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        self.s.listen(5)
        (connection, address) = self.s.accept()
        print repr(connection.recv(5570))
```

This only accepts one connection at a time, does a single read from it, then just leaks the connection, never talking to it again, and goes to get the next client. (I'm also not sure if it is actually valid to call `listen(5)` again on a socket that's already listening, or what it does.) And of course there's no way it can ever finish. (That's not quite true—if, e.g., a client connects and then goes away before you call `recv`, you'll probably get an exception, which you don't catch, so your program will just exit…) Is that what you want?

Also, why `recv(5570)`? That number is the max number of bytes to read, not the port number.

And why print the `repr` of a string?

Meanwhile, do you realize that `recv`, no matter what you pass for the buffer length, is never guaranteed to get an entire message (or to get only one message instead of two, if you had a client that ever sent more than one)? It will almost certainly work that work on localhost, and with such a small message it will likely work *most* of the time on the internet, but not *all* the time.

You also seem to be confused about the difference between class variables and instance variables, because you're setting a bunch of class variables in both `SecureIn` and `SecureOut`. This means that if you could ever have two instances of the class, they'd share the same `SSL.Context`, etc. Even if you don't need to have two simultaneous instances in real life, for testing you'll almost certainly want to create a new instance, and you'll want that to create a new socket, etc., not keep using the old one. So instead of this:

```
class SecureIn(threading.Thread):
  context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
  context.use_privatekey_file('key')
  context.use_certificate_file('cert')
  …
```

Do this:

```
class SecureIn(threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self):
    self.context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
    self.context.use_privatekey_file('key')
    self.context.use_certificate_file('cert')
    …
```

(Or you could put that in the run method, of course.)

Basically, this isn't likely to do anything useful, with or without SSL. I would suggest you take a step back, go over some tutorials, and write something that works with plain-old TCP sockets, and then worry about how to SSL-ize it.

Comment: A) This is all for testing purposes. Like I said, I'm new to this, and it's never going to run anywhere other than localhost.

B) For the purposes of testing, I wanted the server to continue accepting infinitely. 

C) Done all the tutorials, done all the sending and receiving, can get all this to work fine, but the only thing I need that I can't find anywhere is a way for the server to send over the SSL socket.

Comment: OK, maybe if I just ask the simple question, because this isn't meant to be deployed, this is just me trying to get a new concept working, it's not professional, it's never going to be deployed.

So the straight forward question is, how do I get a server to send down an SSL socket in python, without getting that last error message (which is from a different block of code)?

Comment: That error message is not from the `send`, but from the `connect`. You can tell that because it's a "Connection refused", and because the traceback shows the line `s.connect(('localhost', 12345))`. So your problem isn't how to `send` down a socket, it's how to connect the socket in the first place. And the reason it's not working is almost certainly because nobody is listening on port 12345, presumably because the client hasn't yet done its `bind` and `listen` on that socket. Since you've only shown us half the code, and not the half with the problem, all I can do is guess why, so I did.

Comment: @user1585054: Meanwhile, do you know how to use `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat`, `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap`, or other tools for testing socket code? You can verify that someone is listening on localhost:12345, and even use `netcat` and `openssl` together to connect to whatever's on port 12345 and send it data and make sure that works.

Comment: I was making reference to the second error on not being able to send from the server down the ssl socket. That last error comes from the code I've updated the problem with.